# Como sumar floats obtenidos de un diccionario dentro de una lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, float

Hola podeos ayudarme con esto.

```
import os
import sys
import time
root = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
sys.path.append(root + '/python')

import ccxt  # noqa: E402

exchange = ccxt.bitmex({'enableRateLimit' : True})

since = exchange.parse8601('2019-06-11T00:00:00')

symbol = 'BTC/USD'
trades = exchange.fetch_trades(symbol, since )

for element in trades :
        print(element['amount'])

exchange.proxies : (
      {  'http': 'http://10.10.1.10:3128',
        'https': 'https://10.10.1.10:1080',})
```

La  variable `trades` me arroja una lista que contiene `dict`

```
 [{'info': {'timestamp': '2019-06-11T00:00:04.370Z', 'symbol': 'XBTUSD', 'side': 'Sell', 'size': 1009, 'price': 8016, 'tickDirection': 'ZeroMinusTick', 'trdMatchID': 'aa4a0402-edf4-fa60-916c-ad6795d6a90c', 'grossValue': 12587275, 'homeNotional': 0.12587275, 'foreignNotional': 1009},
 'timestamp': 1560211204370, 'datetime': '2019-06-11T00:00:04.370Z', 'symbol': 'BTC/USD', 'id': 'aa4a0402-edf4-fa60-916c-ad6795d6a90c', 'order': None, 'type': None, 'takerOrMaker': None, 'side': 'sell', 'price': 8016.0, 'cost': None, 'amount': 1009.0, 'fee': None}, {'info': {'timestamp': '2019-06-11T00:00:04.370Z', 'symbol': 'XBTUSD', 'side': 'Sell', 'size': 377, 'price': 8016, 'tickDirection': 'ZeroMinusTick', 'trdMatchID': '61eacd7b-3fff-391e-0f3e-37bbcbc49bca', 'grossValue': 4703075, 'homeNotional': 0.04703075, 'foreignNotional': 377}, 'timestamp': 1560211204370, 'datetime': '2019-06-11T00:00:04.370Z', 'symbol': 'BTC/USD', 'id': '61eacd7b-3fff-391e-0f3e-37bbcbc49bca', 'order': None, 'type': None, 'takerOrMaker': None, 'side': 'sell', 'price': 8016.0, 'cost': None, 'amount': 377.0, 'fee': None},
```

Dentro de los diccionarios se repite un `key` lo que quiero es sumar todos los `values` de de los keys. Uso el `for element in trades` para seleccionar el `value` dentro del key `amount`,  pero como este se repite dentro de los diccionarios no hallo la forma de sumar los values.

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la solucion al problema usando un acumulable, si sabeis de un metodo mejor por favor decirme

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys
import time
root = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
sys.path.append(root + '/python')

import ccxt  # noqa: E402

exchange = ccxt.bitmex({'enableRateLimit' : True})
since = exchange.parse8601('2019-06-11T00:00:00')
symbol = 'BTC/USD'
trades = exchange.fetch_trades(symbol, since )
suma = 0
for elements in trades :
        v = elements['info']
        suma += v['size']
print(suma)
exchange.proxies : (
      {  'http': 'http://10.10.1.10:3128',
        'https': 'https://10.10.1.10:1080',})
```

Comment: ¿No te serviría `suma = sum(e['info']['size'] for e in trades)` ?

Comment: Esto es lo que queria lograr

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) para hacerlo de una forma muy rápida y eficiente:

```
suma = sum(float(element['info']['amount']) for element in trade)  # Asumiendo que la cantidad siempre sea un numero
```